# "In the end" or "At the end"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage

Which of these phrases is correct:

> "We are in the end." 
>   "We are at the end."

I know that most of the time when using "at the end" there should be a noun. Like, "...at the end of something". But I also know "in the end" means "finally, at last, or so on.

Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217987/what-differences-are-there-between-at-the-end-and-in-the-end

Answer (score 1):

> In the end.

This refers to a time period. As [Jio points out in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217987/what-differences-are-there-between-at-the-end-and-in-the-end), it's pretty much synonymous with finally.

The [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-end) defines it as - the final result of a series of events, or what is your final conclusion after considering all the relevant facts.

Conversely,

> At the end.

Refers to a position. This doesn't just need to be a physical position though: one can be *at the end* of their life.

---

To bring this back to your question, it really depends on the context. I.e. What you are at/in the end of.

For example: You have just given a presentation - therefore your location in the timescale of the presentation is at the end.

> We are at the end now. Does anyone have any questions?

Or you ask where the snacks are:

> They're over there on the table, at the end.

Imagine that you are summarising that presentation though, as I am about to do with this answer - this is a conclusion which considers the facts:

> In the end, there is only a subtle difference between the two phrases.

[Here is a link from the Merriam Webster Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/in-the-end-at-the-end) with more information.